# Large empty space in Visual Studio Code, need help to wrap my text into this empty area

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to wordwrap to the edge or near the edge of the window in VSC. I've tried changing many settings in both settings and user settings specific to markdown. But nothing changes. I believe there might be an invisible column?

In sublime text I simply add wrap_width of 0.

[image: sreenshot]

You can see there is a large amount of space not being utilized. Can you help me wrap my text into this empty area?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/45653

Comment: thank you. I have tried these things. the issue is that there is a large empty space perhaps a column of some sort. I can easily change the wordwrap settings in and out of markdown, but I can only get words to wrap right next to that empty space. There is probably a way to remove it. I just do not know what settings that relates to, but it's not wordwrap, i believe.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to using a non-monospace font. You can change your font family to a monospace font.